# How can I resample dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have a dataframe with 200 columns whose headers are formatted as datetime

2001-01-01 | 2001-02-01 | 2001-03-01 | and so on

I would like to resample the columns so I get columns of quarterly means

2001q01 | 2001q02 | and so on

Here is my resample line:

```
df.resample('Q', axis=1)
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error because my dataframe as an integer index column and, as I understand it, resample is trying to execute on the index too.

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Can I have a dataframe with no index? If so, how do I create a dataframe with no index? If not, is there a way to call resample on just my columns of data?

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, your column index are not `DatetimeIndex`, you need to convert them to `DatetimeIndex` firstly:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

---

To expand the comments, if your data frame has columns from 7 to 206 related to datetime:

```
datetime_df = df.iloc[:, 7:207]
datetime_df.columns = pd.to_datetime(datetime_df.columns)
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:7], datetime_df.resample("Q", axis=1).mean(), df.iloc[:,208:]], axis = 1)
```

Comment: I can not see your code. How does your `df.columns` look like? is it multi index?

Comment: HousingAll.columns = [pd.to_datetime(x) if 7 <= i <= 206 else x 
        for i, x in enumerate(HousingAll.columns, 1)]

Comment: Sorry for all the comments. Apparently [Enter] key submits the comment and I can't edit after it's submitted.

The problem appears to lie in the fact that my dataframe has more than just datetime columns when I try to use resample function. Is there a way to apply to resample to just a subset of columns in my dataframe?

Comment: Since we are in the comments, I can not go in too much detail. But you can split the datetime columns into a separate data frame, resample and calculate the quarterly means, and then concatenate the result with the non datetime columns. `pd.concat([datetime, nondatetime], axis=1)`.

Comment: Lovely! I considered this but wasn't sure the 2 dataframes' indexes would stay aligned; I was searching for that answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Your columns are not datetime type. You need to convert them to datetime and then resample.

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```